# Using DrawerNavigation with StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So before my app is open it need to logIn/signUp i use for it StackNavigator, then where i successfully logIn, i have mainPage(MapContainer) where i want to use drawerNavigator, all tutors that i saw it just simply example.

**AppRouteConfig**

```
import { createStackNavigator, 
  TabNavigator,
  TabBarBottom, 
  DrawerNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const AppRouteConfig = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: { screen: SignIn },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp},
    ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
    ExploreContainer: { screen: MapContainer }, 
});

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Publish: { screen: Publish}
},
{
  drawerPosition:'left',
  drawerBackgroundColor:'transparent',
  drawerWidth:200,   
});

export default AppRouteConfig;
```

**Publish**

```
export default class PublishRoom extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel:'Publish',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image
                source={require('../img/user.png')}
                style={{width:26, height:26,tintColor:'#964f8e'}}
             />   
        ),
};

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{
            flex:1,
            backgroundColor:'#964f8e',
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent:'center'
            }}>
            <Text style={{
                fontWeight:'bold',
                fontSize:22,
                color:'white'
            }}
            >This is a publish room screen</Text>
                </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Place where i call my Drawer
**AutoComplete**

```
class AutocompleteExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cities: [],
            query: ''
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Icon
                    name="ios-search"
                    size={20}
                    color={colors.gray02}
                    style={styles.searchIcon}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menu}>
                    <Text style={styles.text} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation('DrawerOpen')}>Menu</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default AutocompleteExample;
```

**App**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Root  from './src/navigators/AppRouteConfig';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Root/>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do DrawerNavigator after login / registration on the main page of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the DrawerNavigator as a route in the main StackNavigator:

```
const AppRouteConfig = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: { screen: SignIn },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp},
    ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
    ExploreContainer: { screen: MapContainer },

    // Declare Drawer here:
    DrawerNav: { screen: Drawer }
});

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Publish: { screen: Publish}
},
```

Then, simply navigate with `.navigate('DrawerNav')`

Comment: No it doesnt works, i have an error "DrawerNav is not a react component".